# Can UNIX shared libraries be merged into a single library?

Tags: unix, shared-libraries

I am experimenting with my own BSD or Linux distribution.  I want to organize the system files in a way that makes sense to an end user.  I want them to have access to the system without all the file clutter that *nixes leave around.

Is there a way to merge several dynamic libraries into a single file without losing dynamic linking?  I will have access to all of the source files.

Comment: Which clutter?  All the standard .so files are in a small number of places...

Comment: The end user has no business seeing them. They should all be merged into a big file hog of a file called "Support" inside a system folder.   The cryptic files is what makes UNIX very intimidating to average users.

Comment: Average users shouldn't need to dive around inside `/lib/`, etc.

Comment: @user148298 That sounds really strange. To explore your idea, should there be different versions of the giant "Support" library depending on which libraries the user has installed on their system? Keep in mind that the average Linux distribution has many thousands of different libraries available in it, and no system has every single one of them installed.

Comment: I want to get rid of them too. The file system should be understandable. UNIX has become a big Tower of Babel and it needs some structure and sensibility through a benevolent dictatorship. The user is first, the developer should be last.

Comment: Gobolinux uses a similar idea, you may find inspiration from it.

Comment: @loreb, Thanks! Interesting and similar to my ideas, but it misses the mark by maintaining compatibility with the Tower of Babel ecosystem, rendering it a leaky abstraction. Somewhere behind the thin layer of sheet rock, lurks an entanglement of high voltage wiring ready to incinerate the poor user. My strategy is to enforce strict conventions upon the developer, a proper building code. If you can't meet the building code, you can't install on my OS. Shanty town developments will not be permitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be system-dependent, but at least with ELF (the executable format used by Linux), this is not possible. With ELF, shared libraries are a bit like executables: they are a final product of the linking process and are not designed to be decomposed or relinked into a different arrangement.

If you have the source for all of the components that go into a bunch of shared libraries, I suppose you could link them all together into one giant shared library, but you would use object files (`*.o`) or archive libraries (`*.a`) as the input to produce such a library.

As alluded to in comments, there is unlikely to be a good reason to want to actually do this.

Comment: Thanks. Thousands of files scattered all over the place is great for the computer and the programmer, but is bad for the end user who doesn't have to see these directories and files. It is an eyesore and a leak in the abstraction of data. Would you live in a home where you can easily see and access the plumbing and electrical wiring? If not, then why accept it on your computer?